# Why does a colormap such as viridis give better results for spectrogram-based audio classification over greyscale?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have been trying audio classification on the **UrbanSound8k** dataset and **MPSSC** snore classification dataset. I am using the approach of transfer learning by extracting features from **AlexNet** and **VGG19** pre-trained on **ImageNet**. I am then feeding these features to an **SVM**. Weirdly, I obtain better performance for both the datasets when using the *viridis* colormap as opposed to giving the same 2D grayscale spectrogram array in each of the 3 channels. One thing I don't understand is how does a colormap add any information which wasn't present in the original spectrogram?

I went through answers such as [Do I need 3 RGB channels for a spectrogram CNN?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/426818/do-i-need-3-rgb-channels-for-a-spectrogram-cnn/426942#426942) which say that training a CNN has similar performance when using different colormaps. Is the same true for pre-trained networks too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGG was trained on ImageNet, which is composed of primarily color images, so it's unsurprising that a network which is very good at extracting features from and classify color images produces better results when you feed it in a color image versus a greyscale one.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called pseudo coloring, and has been explored a little bit in the litterature, also outside of pretrained networks.

For example in Sound Event Recognition in Unstructured Environments using Spectrogram Image Processing, PhD thesis by Jonathan William Dennis.